# Can we add multiple values to the same session variable in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-variables

Is it possible to add multiple values in one session  variable ?

In my login page , one session variable is carrying a value, i need to append some other data in same session variable in another page.

In Login.Aspx.Vb

```
   Session.Add("UserKey", "DATA_1_PAGE1 ")
```

In Dashboard.Aspx.Vb

```
   Session.Add("UserKey", "| DATA_2_PAGE2")
```

In Process.Aspx.vb

```
   Dim Session_StateValue = HttpContext.Current.Session("UserKey")
```

In Session_StateValue , I want my values as 'DATA_1_PAGE1| DATA_2_PAGE2'.

Is there any mechanism to append in session variable other than assign to a string and append along with the assigned string once again .

Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with strings, you can use List's, Dictionaries, Arrays, String etc.

Simplest way to concatenate string values would likely be

```
Session.Add("UserKey", "DATA_1_PAGE1")
Session.Add("UserKey", Session("UserKey").ToString() & "| DATA_2_PAGE2")
Dim str As String = Session("UserKey").ToString()
```

Another way could be using a `List(Of String)`

```
Session.Add("key", New List(Of String) From {"string1"})
DirectCast(Session("key"), List(Of String)).Add("string2")
Dim str As String = String.Join("|", DirectCast(Session("key"), List(Of String)).ToArray)
```

Now, based on how your are going to use it, persistence, serialization, etc., one might be more appropriate than the other.

Comment: @jidh Very good then:) ... What do you mean by _strings append mode_?

Answer (score 0):

You can store more than just strings in Session, like `DateTime` or some `Person` object that you defined yourself - how would you have the system implement an "append" then that is valid for all sorts of (combinations of) values?

So the only way is to get the original value as string, append the new value yourself and put that combination in Session.

But make sure then when a user happens to submit that second page twice (the user will always find a way...) you don't append that value twice. Maybe it's better to keep it in separate Session values and only combine them when you need the combined value.